# Process folder path and handle trailing slash in a single line?

Tags: javascript, string

This code accepts a `path/to/folder` or a `path/to/folder/` (notice the trailing slash) and extracts the name of the last folder in the string, i.e.:

```
path = 'path/to/folder'.split('/');
folder = path.pop() || path.pop(); // taking care of trailing slash

// folder == 'folder'
```

I'm curious, is it possible to turn this into a one-liner? I would appreciate both regex and non-regex answers :)

As a side note, I just realized that my code doesn't know how to handle more than one trailing slash (like a typo) - so I'd appreciate it if you could take that into account as well.

Edit: I'm really hoping to see a non-regex answer

Comment: `folder = path.split('/').slice(0, path.split('/').indexOf(''));`, but this works only in modern browsers.

Comment: Clever - why not add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern browsers you can do something like this:

```
folder = (path + '/').split(/\/+|\\+/).slice(0, path.split(/\/+|\\+/).indexOf(''));
```

The code handles also backslashes, even mixed with slashes. A simple [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UYHbU/1/).

Comment: By the way, this way you can work with any number of redundant slashes: `(path + '/').split(/\/+|\\+/).slice(0, path.split(/\/+|\\+/).indexOf(''));`

Comment: @pilau Ofcourse... I've added `+`s to my answer for future visitors, if it's OK?

Comment: Yeah, sure! I'll mark it as a right answer too... doesn't seem like I'll be getting any non-regex answers soon... Cheers for the best solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
path = 'path/to/folder';
folder = path.match(/\/([^\/]+)[\/]*$/)[1]
```

Should work with or without trailing slash and with two slashes too.

Comment: Clean and simple :)

Let's take it up a notch. Say this code is supposed to work on Windows and Unix machines - how would you handle the different slashes?

Comment: I think I'd find something similar to python's os.path.normpath or just replace "\" with "/" before doing a match() :)

Comment: Well we do have Node.js `path` library. But the bigger question is can it be done in a single line? ;)

Comment: Not really important - I like to learn alternative methods of doing things. It gets me familiar with other attitudes towards solving problems, and of course, expands my knowledge of JS. Lately I've been into one-liners. So that's the challenge!